# What business folks have to understand about database design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, data-modeling, rdbms

I have a business team asking me about setting up a meeting to explain them about database design considerations. Since they do not have much idea on RDMS I'm to thinking to explain below things

1. What is RDBMS
2. What is a table and what are constraints / why we need them
3. What is a transaction and what are ACID Properties
4. Things to consider before/while developing a dbms

   a. Decide how much detail you need and how much you may in need future
    b. Identify fields with unique values
    c. Select the appropriate data types for your fields
    d. Normalization and Index design

Also most of the time this team has their data coming in from flat files which we need to load into the DB and represent into the format they need. Anybody please suggest what can i explain more or any better way I can explain. And kind of their data is all over the place. I just want to emphazise more on thinking it through because we couldn't set up a stable process to do the import. Any suggestion for me is welcome as well :)

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Just Google for these terms, or search in SO, looking for reference questions with examples.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes I did and prepaped a presentation. I just mentioned I covered these topics and if anything else anyone would think is necessary to cover to serve the purpose. Thanks!

Comment: To me it seems like you should focus all your time on 4A. Everything else will most likely go over their heads and / confuse them. Explain fields in terms of metrics. Business folks will (hopefully) understand that.

Comment: Thanks! Good advise @SQL_Underworld. I just wanted to give them a little technical insight because sometimes they hear some words go read about it and dont get it right! All I'm going to give them is a pictorial representation with an example! :)

Comment: ACID is a jumbled implementation-oriented approach to *serialized concurrency*: users see transactions serialized. *The ACID paper doesn't even use ACID*. It's just given as listing the "highlights" of implementing serialized transactions. Implementation is irrelevant to users. What they care about is that transactions are submitted any time, but happen sequentially. PS They are developing a *database*. Which they manage via a DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what your audience expects to take away from your presentation.  So I'll have to guess, based on my dealings with business people in the past.  Your mileage may vary.

Business people typically don't care about the skills and knowledge you put into doing a good job with database design, even when they say they do.  They want to understand database design in terms of costs and benefits.  That is how business people think.

So if you must cover some technical topic like indexing, do so from a cost benefit point of view.  There is a cost to adding an index to a table, and there is a benefit to adding an index to a table.  Figuring out in advance whether the benefit is worth the cost is the really tricky part, and they will be interested in this.

On a larger scale, data is a business asset.  There is a cost to managing that asset well, and there is a benefit to managing that asset well.  If you can connect your talk to these two concepts, they will be interested.

If they are really good business people, they will have a good understanding of the subject matter that the database covers, provided it's a part of the enterprise data that affects their business.  If you have a good ER model of the data in the database, this model will connect every value in every table to an attribute, and every attribute will describe some aspect of the subject matter.  This is a very different use of an ER model than just using it as a preliminary to creating a relational model.

Technical people tend to think of ER modeling as "relational modeling light".  It's really much deeper than that. It's an analytical handle on the question "what does the data really mean?"  And this is a handle on "what is the data really worth?".  And this is where the technical world meets the business world.

Comment: Mittyy This makes a lot more sense. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

How about starting from the basis of CRUD operations, then move on to normalization, give the scenarios for the need of Normalization and concept of Keys in RDBMS ,then you can talk about the ER modeling

Comment: Advise taken! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact that you are presenting to business folks, I think there would be 2 approaches best suited to your needs.

a) *WHEN YOU HAVE LESS TIME*:

- Only cover topics which need minimum or no prior knowledge. Cover RDMS & things to consider.
- Keep it simple and easy to understand. Tell them how your solution works and why it is an effective one.
- Cover only topics which are relevant and make it layman friendly. Provide them the pros & cons of your DB design. Connect it to business needs.
- In all cases, provide contextual examples which they may relate to with ease.

b) *WHEN YOU HAVE MORE TIME*

- You may cover topics in detail as suggested in the previous comments. (@SQL_Underworld & @Ramya)